# Get file name and directory in .vimrc file

Tags: vimrc, variables

I have mapped my <kbd>F5</kbd> key in vimrc file to run the code using the following command:

`map <F5> :!sh -xc 'cd "/home/hashir/vscode/" && g++ test.cpp && ./a.out`

It is working well. But it only runs for `test.cpp` file. I want to make it generic by inserting the name of my current file. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%` to expand to the current filename.

See [`:help :!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A%21), which goes into quite some level of detail about that!

> If `{cmd}` contains `%` it is expanded to the current file name.  Special characters are not escaped, use quotes to avoid their special meaning:
>
> ```
> :!ls "%"
> ```

Note also that `:!` will already run the command in a shell for you, so you don't really need a `sh -c '...'` around it.

The reference to the file will be relative to the current directory, so using `cd` here doesn't make much sense, since this will *only* work in `~/vscode`. I'll assume that's the case and I'll remove that as well.

Putting it all together:

```
:map <F5> :!set -x; g++ "%" && ./a.out<cr>
```

---

Vim also has powerful features for building software. Those can be most useful when compiling projects spanning hundreds of source code files, but you *could* leverage them in your particular case too.

They can be quite complex, so it might take a while to get the hang of them. You can start at [`:help :make`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake_makeprg), though you might also try to find easier to digest tutorials about how to use `:make` for your specific language, compiler, build system, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Ex special characters" [`:h cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special).

Specifically, `%` is always replaced in normal Ex commands with the current buffer/file name as long as it's not escaped. So a simple drop-in replacement of "test.cpp" is all that's needed...

```
noremap <F5> :!sh -xc 'cd "/home/hashir/vscode/" && g++ "%" && ./a.out'<CR>
```

(I corrected a couple omissions/typos in your mapping and use "noremap" as is recommended in almost all cases. Also, note quotes around `%` which is best practice kind of thing with shell commands.)

In addition to plain `%` there are a bunch of modifiers that can be appended that will do things like strip off the extension (`%:r`) or force the name to be a full path (`%:p`). See [`:h filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers).

There are also a couple other special chars such as `#` which will be replaced by the "alternate" file/buffer name.

By the way, if you wanted to use a plain `%` in your shell command you'd have to escape it by preceding it with backslash <kbd>\</kbd> as I alluded to before.